# SQL: how can I exclude certain lines from an aggregated result?

Tags: sql, postgresql, logic, aggregate-functions

In the query I built, the result shows something like below:

```
SELECT name
      ,ARRAY_AGG(fruits ORDER BY time ASC) AS all_fruits
FROM table_fruits
```

| name | all_fruits |
| --- | --- |
| Person A | Apple, Banana, Apple, Apple, Apple, Apple |
| Person B | Apple, Apple, Apple, Banana, Apple, Banana |
| Person C | Banana, Banana, Apple, Banana, Apple, Apple |

I want to add one more column which shows the count of apples. However, I do not want to count apples that are followed by bananas. Therefore, the additional column should look like below.

| name | all_fruits | count_of_apple |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | Apple, Banana, Apple, Apple, Apple, Apple | 4 |
| Person B | Apple, Apple, Apple, Banana, Apple, Banana | 2 |
| Person C | Banana, Banana, Apple, Banana, Apple, Apple | 2 |

How would I do this in SQL? The source includes time for when the fruit was eaten.

Comment: It may be easier to do this operation before the aggregation you're doing. Can you share your query and samples from your previous input table?

Comment: Also can you update your post by tagging the DBMS you're currently using?

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question and added some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check:

- for each row you have in your parent table, what "*fruits*" value follows that row with the [`LEAD`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-lead-function/) window function
- if the row in check is the last one, it won't have a next value (it will be NULL), so the [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-coalesce/) function will replace this NULL value with the current "*fruits*" value
- hence you can assign 1 to your new column when the current "*fruits*" value is `"Apple"` and your next value is not `"Banana"`, inside a `CASE` statement

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN fruits = 'Apple'
             AND COALESCE(LEAD(fruits) OVER(
                              PARTITION BY name 
                              ORDER     BY time), 
                          fruits)                  <> 'Banana'
            THEN 1 
       END AS apples_not_after_bananas
FROM table_fruits
```

After this step, you can use your own code and add

- the `GROUP BY` clause you missed, to aggregate over the "*name*" field
- the `SUM` aggregation function over the previously generated `1`s when apples were not followed by bananas.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN fruits = 'Apple'
                 AND COALESCE(LEAD(fruits) OVER(
                                  PARTITION BY name 
                                  ORDER     BY time), 
                              fruits)                  <> 'Banana'
                THEN 1 
           END AS apples_not_after_bananas
    FROM table_fruits
)
SELECT name,
       ARRAY_AGG(fruits ORDER BY time ASC) AS all_fruits,
       SUM(apples_not_after_bananas)       AS count_of_apple
FROM cte
GROUP BY name
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5B8pnv9xEdBUBfVoU8fjkY/0).

---

**Edit**: the banana came more than 1 day later

If you want to add this specific condition, or in general any conditions, you need to work inside the CASE statement, which currently has two conditions, one on the current fruit and one on the next fruit.

Checking whether the banana came more than 1 day later just means to add something like this:

```
           CASE WHEN fruits = 'Apple'
                 AND COALESCE(LEAD(fruits) OVER(
                                  PARTITION BY name 
                                  ORDER     BY time), 
                              fruits)                  <> 'Banana'
               --AND <if difference between the current next time value is greater than 1 day>
                THEN 1 
           END AS apples_not_after_bananas
```

Comment: I would like to try adding one more condition which is to exclude apples followed by bananas within 1 day. So even if an apple is followed by a banana, if the banana came more than 1 day later than the apple, I would still like to count that apple. Any tips on how to make this possible?

Comment: Updated my answer with a solid guideline to follow, for this condition and any other potential condition. @user16462786